# Sum and Compare columns in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

This may be really nothing but as i am new to hive. I don't know how to do this in Hive?

I have a sample dataset that looks like this:

```
    column_A       column_B    column_C
       1             1          0
       1             1          0
       1             0          1
```

Now, i need to find out the sum of each column and then compare them to get the highest.

for example:

```
 column_A       column_B    column_C
    3              2            1
```

Output should be:

```
  column_A   
     3
```

Query that I wrote is unable to perform the sum of  each columns and compare columns to find the greatest among them.

```
SELECT (sum(column_A) as A,sum(column_B) as B,sum(column_C) as C) as xyz
from table_name where A IN (SELECT GREATEST(A,B,C) from xyz) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `greatest()` *after* the aggregation:

```
SELECT greatest(sum(column_A), sum(column_B), sum(column_C)) 
from table_name;
```